# SQL Server edition update

Tags: sql-server-2012

We have a database in SQL Server 2012 with data of 1.3 TB in size. Our current edition is Standard and configured in a failover cluster mode. We are planning to upgrade our edition from Standard to Enterprise.

So my questions are:

- Is it possible to upgrade without downtime? As I know maintenance plan need to execute in one node. In my case can I execute it on the passive node without downtime?
- What is the best backup method for 1 TB database. Backup/ Restore is enough for this size?
- Does it necessary to take backup and restore after up-gradation? I mean the possibility of data corrupt during the update of edition.
- Our server has 16 core processor and we have 4 licenses of 4 core server (4 x 4 = 16). Should we put only one license copy?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to upgrade without downtime? As I know maintenance plan
>   need to execute in one node. In my case can I execute it on the
>   passive node without downtime?

The services will need to be restarted to pick up the new settings. You will also likely be instructed to restart your server. However, upgrading the secondary node and [failing over is an option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/upgrade-a-sql-server-failover-cluster-instance?view=sql-server-2017).

> What is the best backup method for 1 TB database. Backup/ Restore is
>   enough for this size?

1TB is large, but large is relative. Following normal backup and restore procedures is the way to go. You want to make sure you are using page verification = CHECKSUM, backup verification & checksum, and if you are worried about the size of the backup then compression.

> Does it necessary to take backup and restore after up-gradation? I
>   mean the possibility of data corrupt during the update of edition.

Dozens of things could go wrong. I could caution against an in-place *upgrade* which is what you are proposing. If something goes wrong, there is no "back button". It would be much wiser to set up new servers, cluster, etc and restore your backup to the new instance after testing is complete.

> Our server has 16 core processor and we have 4 licenses of 4 core
>   server (4 x 4 = 16). Should we put only one license copy?

This question depends on what HA/DR you are going to, and what you plan to use the secondary for if you are using AGs. I say this because I assume there is a Enterprise level feature you want to use, or a few of them. However, licensing questions should be discussed with the vendor.

Comment: Are you sure that you can't upgrade the secondary node of a FCI, and then failover and patch the old primary?

Comment: @ErikDarling I skimmed over the FCI part of the question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @erikDarling does it necessarily to migrate/restore data after update edition?

Comment: @MoinulIslam you should ask the person who answered your question. I have no opinion on the matter.

Comment: @scsimon does it necessarily to migrate/restore data after update edition?

Comment: No. You'd upgrade your passive node (which removes it from the list of owners while it's being upgraded) and then either fail-over or an automatic fail-over will occur making your upgraded node the primary node. Then, you'll upgrade the other node.